# AngularJs how to make sure code executed synchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button on a page which calls the process function within a controller but before I post the details I need to get the 
user details and userGroup details, and finally  post the user details.

But when I debug this I can see my populateUserGroups function is called but without getting the details the updateUser function is called hence the posted data does not have the userGroup data.

It seems the populateUserGroups function is called asynchronously, how can I make sure when users click the Process button, first **getData** is called,
then **populateUserGroups** is called and **$scope.user.userGroups** is populated with the returned data and finally **updateUser** is called?

```
    $scope.process = function () {
        myservice.getData($scope.userId).success(function (data) {

                $scope.user = data.value;
                $scope.user.userGroups = {};

                $scope.populateUserGroups();
                $scope.updateUser();

        });
    };

    $scope.populateUserGroups = function () {
        myservice.getUserGroups($scope.userId).success(function (groupData) {
            $scope.user.userGroups = groupData;
        });
    };

    $scope.updateUser = function() {
        myservice.updateUser($scope.user).success(function () {

            // do stuff

        });
    };
```

Comment: Call the second function in the first function's callback?

Comment: Use promises ideally with services that return promises. See $q

Comment: use async,https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Answer (score 1):

use $q.all

```
$q.all([
  myservice.getData($scope.userId),
  myservice.getUserGroups($scope.userId)
]).then(function(resps){
  $scope.user = resps[0].value;
  $scope.user.userGroups = resps[1].data;

  $scope.populateUserGroups();
  $scope.updateUser();
})
```